# Droid base and iPhone cable for charging?

Tags: iphone, charging, charger

I just got an iPhone 5c.  I had a Droid.  I have several Droid charging cables.  The Lightening charging cable I got with my iPhone detaches on the other end to a USB port.  The Droid charging "bases"/wall outlets have USB ports.  Can I recharge my iPhone 5 by plugging the Apple Lightning cable into a Droid base?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases yes you can.

But if the charger is too weak (less than 1 amps), it will charge your iPhone more slowly than the original charger.